# Detecting Keyboard Visible with Lua on Corona SDK

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

Due to the location of my 2 text boxes towards the bottom of the screen, I have developed the following code to shift my text boxes to a new position when either one is touched (so as to prevent keyboard overlap):

```
local textField = native.newTextField( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY + 60, 200, 40 )
textField.placeholder = "Email"
textField.isEditable = true

local textField2 = native.newTextField( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY + 110, 200, 40 )
textField2.placeholder = "Password"
textField2.isEditable = true

 --function to handle events

 local function touchListener(oEvent)
    local oTextField = oEvent.target

    if "began" == oEvent.phase then

      textField.y = display.contentCenterY - 120
      textField2.y = display.contentCenterY - 70
      myText.y = 55

      local button2 = widget.newButton
{
    x = display.contentCenterX,
    y = display.contentCenterY - 20,
    id = "loginbutton",
    defaultFile = "buttonDefault.png",
    font = "Georgia",
    labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } },
    label = "Login"

}

    elseif "editing" == oEvent.phase then

    elseif "submitted" == oEvent.phase then

      textField.y = display.contentCenterY - 120
      textField2.y = display.contentCenterY - 70
      myText.y = 55

      button2.isVisible = false
      native.setKeyboardFocus( nil ) --hides keyboard

    elseif "ended" == oEvent.phase then

        textField.y = display.contentCenterY + 60
        textField2.y = display.contentCenterY + 110
        myText.y = display.contentCenterY - 3


    end
end

textField:addEventListener( "userInput", touchListener )
```

Could some body please assist me in how I might go about detecting with Lua when the keyboard is not visible, so that if a user exits the text box (either by pressing away or by pressing the "back" feature on the Android) I can do it so the text boxes go back to there original positions?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to create all the widgets you need and hide/show only when needed. For example,

1. create `textfield`, `textfield2`, and `button2` in your scene initialzation (like `createScene` event handler), and you set a tap listener on both text fields. Set a click listener on the button.
2. In the tap listener, you move both text fields, and make the button visible.
3. In the button click handler, you restore the y position of both text fields, and hide the button.